# Последовательное выполнение запросов SQL UPDATE в С#

Tags: c#, sql, ado

```
cn.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE fields SET saved = '', tryes = 0 ";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE razdel SET e_time = 0 , tryes = 0 ";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE sign SET clicked = 0";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Правильно или нет? Есть ли другой вариант?

Comment: Слово time зарезервированное слово. Попробуйте использовать [time]. На ваш вопрос сложно ответить, так как необходимо знать на какой из трех команд валится ошибка. Возможно, ошибка с типами данных.

Comment: @rogueCapella Что-то по поводу [time] не подумал ) а насчёт `BeginExecuteNonQuery` не в курсе? Вроде подходит, но на msn там сложно описано

Comment: @rogueCapella Всё отработало замечательно, но всё таки интересно как будет более правильно выполнять операции подобного рода, когда требуется последовательно выполнять много запросов без ответа

Comment: BeginExecuteNonQuery используется для асинхронного выполнения запроса. Если не работали с асинхронностью, то лучше не использовать.

Comment: "как правильно выполнять..." на данный вопрос вам ответили ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а разве

```
cn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE fields SET saved = '', tryes = 0;
                   UPDATE razdel SET e_time = 0 , tryes = 0;
                   UPDATE sign SET clicked = 0;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

не пройдет?

ну либо (правда не знаю быстрее будет или нет)

```sql
UPDATE fields,
       razdel,
       sign
SET fields.saved = '',
    fields.tryes = 0,
    razdel.e_time = 0,
    razdel.tryes = 0,
    sign.clicked = 0
```